# Sending command line to the main method in Java

Tags: java

I got a problem like this. The command line passes to the main method is, - A . But when it sends the "-" is not printed back. Doesn't it get the "-" as a command line. Are there any other characters like that? Or are there any other reasons behind it?

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String s="";
        for(int x=0; ++x<args.length;){
            s+=args[x];
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

command line-

```
java NewClass - A .
```

The answer got was only A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your for loop is wrong. This is how it should be.

```
for(int x = 0; x < args.length; x++) {
```

Add a comment if you need explanation as to why.

Answer (score 1):

Please review your for loop definition:

```
for(int x=0; ++x<args.length;){
```

`++x` means: increment `x`, then use it. So, `x` first becomes 1 then is used in comparison and in access to `args` array.

Change this to:

```
for (int x = 0; x < args.length; x++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You loop is wrong.

Try this:

```
for(int x=0; x<args.length;x++){
```